# Fallback for binding to a nested property in XAML

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, xaml, data-binding

I use WPF to display and edit a database managed by the Entity Framework.
As databases go, some properties of my classes are actually references to other tables, and some of these are optional.

Now I would still like to display a text box (or more suitable control) where the user can edit the content of such a nested property, creating it on the fly when the data binding writes it to the source.

Ex:

```
class Entry
{
    // ...
    public virtual Comment MyComment {get;set;} // Raises PropertyChangedEvent
}

class Comment
{
    // ...
    public string Text {get;set;} // Raises PropertyChangedEvent
}
```

In XAML, the surrounding `DataContext` is set to an existing `Entry` from the database. A text box is bound to the `Text` property of a `Comment`. The comment might not exist.

```
<TabControl DataContext="{Binding InstanceOfEntry}">
    <!-- ... -->
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Comment.Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</TabControl>
```

What does not work:

- **FallbackValue** or **TargetNull**: These would work on a `string` in my example (the `Comment.Text`) and not on the `Comment` itself.
- **MultiBinding**: I tried to split the data binding `Path` up into its components and set the `Comment` part as DataContext of a surrounding element. Using a converter I could insert a fallback comment when the database did not contain one for the `Entry`. But I have no idea how to attach that to the `Entry` once the comment was altered. My `ConvertBack` is never called (and thinking about it, I don't know why it should …).
- **PriorityBinding**: As with my multi binding attempt, it could be used with a dummy `Comment`, but it would not be written to the `Entry` from the DataContext.

TL/DR: Is there a way to trigger the creation of an object in the binding path?

```
    Entry.null.string

    string is edited using data binding
    *xaml magic happens*

--> Entry.Comment.string
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is only sort of an answer to my own question.
I am still searching for the "xaml way to do it".

What I now did was to rebuild some part of the data structure in my view model.

```
class ViewModel
{
    public Entry MyEntry {get;set;}

    public Comment CurrentComment
    {
        get
        {
            if (MyEntry.Comment != null)
                return MyEntry.Comment;

            var c = new Comment();
            c.PropertyChanged += CommentChanged;
            return c;
        }
    }
}
```

With the additional touch, that the new `Comment` isn't just returned: I subscribe to its `PropertyChanged` event with a handler that reattaches it to the `MyEntry` instance every time it is modified.

```
void CommentChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyEntry.Comment = sender as Comment;
}
```

It's as ugly as it sounds (worse actually, because I have to filter for validation properties etc.), so better ways are still appreciated.